Get all columns in table with example result set
I'm working on analysing a database. The way I'm doing this is by getting a tables columns and an example of a row. This would come out like this:



FieldName
Value




Id
0


Name
Bob



My current query is like this:
SELECT FieldName, Value
FROM 
   (SELECT TOP 1
       isnull(CAST([Id] AS varchar(MAX)),'no-data') as Id
      ,isnull(CAST([Name] AS varchar(MAX)),'no-data') as Name
    FROM person
    ORDER BY id desc) p
UNPIVOT
   (Value FOR FieldName IN
      ([Id]
      ,[Name])
   ) AS unpvt;

My issue is, for every table I have to rebuild the query. Is there any other way I can do this that is repeatable across tables?

You can start by querying the Schema for all tables SELECT TABLE_NAME  FROM [<DATABASE_NAME>].INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES  WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' and then query each of the results for columns  SELECT COLUMN_NAME   FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS   WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'yourTableName' with a CTE an work from there

Do you want all the tables in a single query or do you want the result set to only return a single table? Either way you will need to utilize dynamic sql for this.

@SeanLange I only need to return a single table at a time.

Then use the solution posted below by siggemannen and add a where clause where t.name = 'YourTable'.

Here' one quick idea to get you started:
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT  @sql = STRING_AGG(CAST(CONCAT('select [key] as ', quotename(name), N', Value as value from openjson((select top 1 * from ', quotename(name), ' x FOR JSON PATH, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES), ''$[0]'')
') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), N'')
FROM    sys.tables t

EXEC    (@sql)

It generate a long string of dynamic sql which in it's turn unpivots a single row per table and displays it.
Here's an output sample:



spt_monitor
value




lastrun
2022-10-08T06:31:55.527


cpu_busy
23


io_busy
141


idle
3892


pack_received
39


pack_sent
39


connections
69


pack_errors
0


total_read
0


total_write
0


total_errors
0






MSreplication_options
value




optname
transactional


value
true


major_version
90


minor_version
0


revision
0


install_failures
0




This will be an issue with larger databases because STRING_AGG will max out at 8,000 characters. But if you limit this to a single table it is just about perfect.

I adjusted your query to this:
SELECT [key] as 'FieldName', Value from openjson((select top 1 * from person x for json path, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES ), '$[0]')

This includes null values in the result and only targets one table. If you adjust your answer to include this, that'd be great.

If you're gonna use dynamic SQL not sure why you wouldn't just get the column names from sys.columns?

@MartinSmith, cause i wanted to use the cool for json unpivot trick? :D

True - is still a lot less tedious than the code to unpivot all the columns by name (and cast all the values)

Please try the following solution based on JSON.
It will work starting from SQL Server 2016 onwards.
No need in any dynamic SQL.
Notable points:

ORDER BY NEWID() clause gives a random row in a table.
And it has an exception list, just in case.

SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, FName VARCHAR(20), LName VARCHAR(20), Place VARCHAR(20));
INSERT @tbl (FName, LName, Place) VALUES
('Jane', 'Paulin' , NULL),
('Marin', 'Marconi' , 'Spain'),
('Bill', 'Doherty', 'UK');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT TOP(1) * FROM @tbl ORDER BY NEWID()
)
SELECT seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID)
      , ColumnName  = B.[Key]
      , Value = B.[Value]
FROM rs AS A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT * 
            FROM  OPENJSON((SELECT A.* FOR JSON PATH,WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES)) 
            WHERE [Key] NOT IN ('id','Other','Columns','ToExclude') -- exception list
             ) AS B;

Output



seq
ColumnName
Value




1
FName
Jane


2
LName
Paulin


3
Place
NULL



